# Start SWT application after system start

Tags: raspberry-pi, java, startup, raspbian

I am trying to start a java SWT application after the system has booted and the user has logged in on a debian based distro (RaspbianOS on a Raspberry Pi). Therefore I have added the line `sh <path>/startProgram.sh` into the `rc.local` file.

I know that the start-script is getting called because I created a new directory for debug purposes in this script. Apart from that the script looks like this:

```
java -jar /home/pi/Downloads/AlarmClock.jar
```

And if I double click it manually it starts the application just fine. However it won't start at boot of the system. My first thought was that the X-server has not yet been initialized at that point but according to [this article](https://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/) the `rc.local` script is the very last init script to run and therefore the x-server should be initialized by then (at least according to my understanding)

Does anyone has an idea on how to start the program that will create a GUI after user login?

Comment: You don't tell us if your program needs a running Xserver instance and a window manager. The service "x11-common", which is started at boot, does not start the Xserver - it's task is to "set up the X server and ICE socket directories". The Xserver and window manager is started by `lightdm` when logging in.

Comment: Well I am creating a graphical user interface via `SWT` therefore I simply assumed that I need the Xserver running for that...

Comment: Could it be that I need to place my script into `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d`? Or does that directory serve another purpose?

Comment: As stated before there is no Xserver running after boot, and no GUI application possible before logging in - see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/LightDM/. If you want to have some program running with GUI before logging in, try to get familiar with [greeters](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/LightDM/Development/)

Comment: `xinitrc`(global or userlocal) is run by [xinit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinit). This is used to manually start the Xserver; I don't believe you can have an Xserver started this way at boot and in parallel have a displaymanager for logging in...

Comment: Ah okay that is good to know. But what I actually want is to start the GUI after the login so as soon as the user will see the desktop... I need to edit that in my question as well

Comment: Search for `raspbian autostart`. Depends on your preferred window manager. For lxde, see http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-autostart-apps-in-rasbian-lxde-desktop/

Comment: Yeah I have found that one but it doesn't work. I guess that is because I'm trying to run a script and not an application. I have also tried to use `~/.config/autostart` and `/etc/xdbg/autostart` but none of them worked either. Now I have put it in `/etc/profile.d` and this does start the app but it's now unclosable xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it turned out the way to go is to create a `dektop entry` in `~/.config/autostart` that then runs the script starting my application (I guess it would also work when starting it directly from there).

Note:
A desktop entry has to have the extension `.desktop` otherwise it won't work even if the content is correct.