# How to run files automatically after I power on my raspberry pi?

Tags: networking, scripting, raspberry-pi, startup

Is there anyway to have files (texts/videos) saved in a specific folder to run automatically once I start up my raspberry pi?

I am creating a LAN of raspberry pi's with one central laptop connected to the rest of the pis. The files are uploaded on the laptop and shared to the raspberry pis. I would like to have specific files (all different for each pi) to open once I turn on a pi.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/360735/117549

Comment: If you are using a `systemd` based distro on your Pi, such as Raspbian, you could create a [custom service file](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md) and tell it to [run at a particular time during/after boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/84892/run-python-script-at-startup-with-systemd-service)

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest to use rsync though samba?
Using this solution you can create like a dropbox-style folder, which can be automatically synchronized.